# Как отправить видео на почту?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

При загрузки видео в шаблон для письма, используя плагин TinyMCE не приходит видео на почту mail.ru.Как отправить видео на почту чтобы оно пришло в теле письма, не прикрепленным и чтобы можно было просмотреть с письма не переходя на другой сайт. Письма доходят,а вот самого видео нет.

```
 //WYSIHTML5 Editor
      if ($('#marketing_emails_content').length)
      {
        // $('#marketing_emails_content').wysihtml5();
        $('#marketing_emails_content').tinymce(
          {
            width: '100%',

            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url : '/assets/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
            content_css : '/assets/tinymce/styles/default.css',

            // General options
            theme: "modern",
            visual_table_class: 'table',
            removed_menuitems: 'newdocument',
            font_formats: "Verdana=verdana,arial,sans-serif;Calibri=calibri,sans-serif;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier;Georgia=georgia,serif;Lucida Console=lucida;Times New Roman=times new roman;Segoe UI=segoe ui;Roboto=roboto",
            fontsize_formats: "8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
            plugins: [
              "advlist autolink autosave link image jbimages lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
              "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
              "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
              ],        
            toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
            toolbar2: "bullist numlist | undo redo | link image jbimages media code | insertdatetime preview | table | template | removeformat | subscript superscript",
            templates: "/ajax/services/get_email_layouts",
            relative_urls: false,
            remove_script_host: false,
            branding: false
          });
      }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85345/discussion-on-question-by-vladimir-marakhovskii-----).

Answer (score -1):

Давайте начнем с начала. 
А с начала нужно понять что такое письмо с точки зрения единицы данных.

[Письмо](http://www.antispam.ru/4user/reading-email-headers-translation.shtml) - это один единственный файл в котором хранятся все данные письма.
  Письмо становится письмом благодаря заголовкам которые читают почтовые программы.
  Все бинарные данные письма как минимум кодируются в [base64.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Давайте поразмыслим, можно ли передать видео в письме ? Представьте не очень большое видео имеет размер например 20 мегабайт (30, 40 ?)

Давайте еще подумаем, что происходит когда вы через TinyMCE вставляете видео в шаблон ? Думаете происходит кодировка видео ? Нет, просто вставляется ссылка.

Стоит ли дальше размышлять на эту тему ? 
Короче говоря, не стоит пытаться пересылать видео в письме, зато самое время прочитать как выглядить электронное письмо :)

Comment: видео лежит у меня на сервере. Но нужно чтобы в том же gmail или другом почтовом сервисе можно было просмотреть в теле письма, а  не на стороннем сайте.К сожалению тот же Ютуб, вставляет  <iframe> и банется службами почтовых сервисов. Есть ли какой либо другой вариант для корректной отправки видео в письме?